# How to use Database in Flash App?

Tags: flash

I just beginning with flash, someone can help me explain a few issues below

I create a project in Flash CC and it have 4 type:

- Action script 3.0
- AIR for Desktop
- AIR for Android
- AIR for iOS

So, the difference between them?

I created a project Action Script 3.0 and it can't use slqLite. So, which database I can use for a project Action Script 3.0? 
If your answer is use AIR, let me know: Can AIR run on web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe® AIR® includes the capability of creating and working with local SQL databases. The runtime includes a SQL database engine with support for many standard SQL features, using the open source SQLite database system.However,AIR can't run on web, it's aim to mobile and desktop.

If you want to use database for a pure as3 project ,the class 'ShareObject' may help you,the 'SharedObject' class is used to read and store limited amounts of data on a user's computer or on a server.Otherwise, you have to access server through http or socket to use database.